# Managing datasets for a branch/tangled network

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to setup up two networks that meet in a couple of fully connected layers to a single output layer. I think I know how to get the branches setup (though additional resources for that would be nice), but I'm unclear on how to manage my dataset. One of the branches is working on a dataset of text documents that I gather through the preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory() function then do some convolution over it, while the other is a set of corresponding numbers I'd like to input into the second branch, that is stored as a .csv. I'm not entirely sure how to make sure the values and the text files are input into the network simultaneously, any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

(For additional context I currently have the network that works on the text documents working, I'm trying to add a branch of supplementary data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very well explained in the tensorflow documentation. The following style of code will work.

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

```
model.fit(
    {"title": title_data, "body": body_data, "tags": tags_data},
    {"priority": priority_targets, "department": dept_targets},
    epochs=2,
    batch_size=32,
)
```